# pylons file uploading - access 1st file

Tags: python, file-upload, pylons

Currently, I'm using request.params["filename"] to access uploaded files.

In Pylons, what is the syntax to access a file if you don't know the filename, something like request.files[0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what this: http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/1.0/forms/#file-uploads page says, you could search through the params or request.POST looking for values of the type cgi.FieldStorage

Answer (score 0):

It's not the *file* name that's used as a key in request.params, it's the *field* name that was used in the HTML: `<input type="file" name="fieldname">`